# Erlang help: Using an If Statement in an anonymous function

Tags: if-statement, erlang, anonymous-function, higher-order-functions

So I installed the Erlang plugin for IntelliJ and I'm running into a roadblock. I have an anonymous function and I inserted an if statement into it. That should work, but it doesn't.

```
Max_Fun = fun(X, Max) -> if
                          X > Max -> X;
                          X <= Max -> Max
                         end
```

See my issue is that the less than or equal to comparison has a red squiggly underline. When I hover over it I am told " '<=' unexpected "
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
Max_Fun = fun(X, Max) -> if
                                 X > Max -> X;
                                 X =< Max -> Max
                             end
              end.
```

> When I hover over it I am told " '<=' unexpected " Why is this
>   happening and how can I fix it?

Easy rule in erlang is that the comparison operators never look like arrows. So when you think you should type <= it is actually =<

Comment: So the other version would be ">=". With the equals sign last?

Comment: Do you know what the reasoning behind this syntax is?

Comment: Erlang have reserved the arrow notation, for example this is the notation used for Maps in erlang: #{a => 2, b => 3}. But even before erlang got maps  in to the language I think the reasoning was that =>  and <= looked to much like the other arrows used, which would be confusing.

Comment: The arrow `<=` is used for a long time by bitstring comprehension: `<< << (X*2) >> || <<X>> <= << 1,2,3 >> >>.`